# ShieldUI barcode Text setFontSize

Tags: wicket, barcode, font-size, shieldui

I am trying to generate a barcode, using ShieldUI for Wicket.

For the barcode, I also need to display the text.

I am trying to set the size of the text, but the output is not good, the barcode somehow overflows of setting the text size.

```
Barcode barcode = new Barcode(fieldName);
BarcodeOptions options = barcode.getOptions();

options.setValue("123456");
options.setType(BarcodeOptions.Type.CODE_128);
options.setHeight(30);
options.setWidth(120);

options.text.enabled=true;
options.text.style.setFontSize("8"); //if I remove this, the barcode 
//shows ok, but the textsize is not the one that I desire

item.add(barcode);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="egp/css/shieldui-all.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="egp/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="egp/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="egp/js/shieldui-barcode.min.js"></script>
<wicket:head>

</wicket:head>
</head>
<body>
<table wicket:id="forEach">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div
                        wicket:id="barcode">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AORJr.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed that problem and reported to ShieldUI. They have uploaded a fix. The problem was fixed by changing fontSize from string to integer. Probably you need to download latest version and test.